# CTE with multiple rows and tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a problem with CTE, below my tables:

Table: Purchase

```
PID      szProductID     curQty        curPrice
1        001             10            100
2        001             30            200
3        001             50            300
```

and

Table: Sales

```
SID      szProductID     curQty        curSalesPrice
1        001             15            500
2        001             5             400
3        001             5             400
4        001             5             400
5        001             40            400
```

And I want to show those tables like below:

Result

```
SID      szProductID     curQty        curSalesPrice   curPurchasePrice
1        001             10            500             100
1        001             5             500             200
2        001             5             400             200
3        001             5             400             200
4        001             5             400             200
5        001             5             400             200
5        001             35            400             300
```

Basically, its just like a FIFO method..

I've found many CTE samples but they only compare many rows to one row, and sometimes i found an error : 'The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.' when i tried those samples...

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: have you tried anything at all?if so, please post your attempt

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 1):

SQL will default cap out at 100 recursions unless you specify otherwise.  You can get past 100 by using this at the end of your query.

```
OPTION (MAXRECURSION *NUMBER UP TO 32767 HERE*)
```